# Python: Output list of folders in given path

Tags: python

Given:

```
/some/path/to/a/certain unspecified/folder/
```

I need a list:

```
var = some, path, to, a, "certain unspecified", folder
```

I suspect `os.walk(dir)` might have something to do with it, but I can't seem to make this work...

Sorry I'm fairly new to Python.

Comment: I think you mean `var = ["some", "path", "to", "a", "certain unspecified", "folder"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer to **except what happens when the user is on a Windoze machine, and the dir is '\'**

Use `os.sep` to get the path separator of current os:

```
In [254]: os.getcwd()
Out[254]: 'D:\\Documents\\Desktop'

In [255]: os.getcwd().split(os.sep)
Out[255]: ['D:', 'Documents', 'Desktop']
```

Comment: Perefect. os.sep seems to be key

Answer (score 1):

split is the key:

```
var = '/some/path/to/a/certain unspecified/folder/'.split('/')
```

Comment: oooh. Split looks like it may do... --- except what happens when the user is on a Windoze machine, and the dir is '\'

Comment: and `os.listdir` gives the contents of that path... not quite the same

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're on windows, mangling linux paths, use `os.path.split`.
Or set [`os.sep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.sep) to your liking.
This is not going to work with mixed windows and linux paths, unless you change the path separator appropriately, just before `split`ting.

Edit2: Setting `os.path.sep` WON'T make `os.path.split` or `os.path.join` behave any different. Sorry.

Edit: Um, right, `os.path.split` gets the final component.
There is, however, `os.altsep`, so `path.replace(os.altsep,os.sep).split(os.sep)` might be the way.

[`os.sep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.sep) is by default set to your OS' preferred one.
[`os.pathsep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.pathsep) is (on windows) what separates directories in PATH variable.

To make it reliable normalize the path (as suggested by @mhlester):

```
>>> os.path.normpath(r"C:/PythoN27\python.exe")
'C:\\PythoN27\\python.exe'
>>> os.path.normcase(r"C:/PythoN27\python.exe")
'c:\\python27\\python.exe'
```

Comment: the environment will be stable - just can't control what enviro it'll be run in...

Comment: This is possibly the better answer than mine. It depends on how the path is built. Most of the time I spend on Windows still uses '/', but likely it should be normalized first regardless.

Comment: `os.path.split('/a/b/c/d')` yields `('/a/b/c', 'd')`. That is not what OP want.